# org-mode and reftex giving this error: reftex-using-biblatex-p: Stack overflow in regexp matcher

Tags: org-mode, reftex-mode, bibtex

I'm trying to set upt `org-mode` and `reftex-mode` but I'm getting some troubles. Here is my `init.el` file:

```
;; ORG-MODE
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
(setq org-agenda-files '("~/.../"))
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (reftex-mode)
        (visual-line-mode)
        (company-mode)))
```

I'm trying to load a `.bib` file with `(setq reftex-default-bibliography '("path/to/bibfile.bib"))` and it seems to work fine, but as I type `C-c [` in order to add a new reference I got this error:

`reftex-using-biblatex-p: Stack overflow in regexp matcher`

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

*P.S. couldn't tag with* `reftex-mode` *nor* `bibtex` *as I have no enough reputation score. If anyone could, I think thah would be good!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reftex-using-biblatex-p` is a simple function that finds whether the tex package `biblatex` is used by searching the text. The error may occur when the `org` file to be parsed is very large. So you can try a small file, or disable this function temporarily by `(fset 'reftex-using-biblatex-p 'ignore)`, and see if `reftex` works.

Comment: Can you please advise, @liuhui, why this happens with large org files?  Is there a way to increase the maximum file size for which this works, by adapting some configuration parameter?